# I want the old Gallery app back

Tags: nexus-4, gallery, 5.0-lollipop

So, my Nexus 4 got Lollipop, nullifying the old/default Gallery app. I hate the Google+ app, a lot, especially it's gallery "replacement". Other gallery apps from the market. None of them are what I want.

All I want is the old Gallery app back.

What I've tried:

- Copying old app and installing it with the UI. App not installed.
- `adb -r -d` fails with `Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES]`
- `adb uninstall com.google.gallery` fails with `Failure [DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR]`

Rooting isn't a practical option at this point.

Comment: I got old gallery app but editing the photo will stop the gallery app

Comment: @sameer Could you upload the app somewhere? My apk isn't from my Nexus.

Comment: Google nexus gallery apk

Comment: I am officially a dunce. That worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had a bad apk. Got a new one, works fine.